# Merging 2 sql queries into a single one

Tags: mysql, sql, geospatial, geo

I have two sql queries which when run independent produces the correct results

Query 1

```
SELECT id,
(6371 * acos( cos( radians(9.977364864079215) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(76.58620953448485) ) + sin( radians(9.977364864079215) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) 
            AS distance 
            FROM geodata HAVING distance < 20 
            ORDER BY distance 
            LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

Query 2

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.* FROM schools e  
WHERE (
    (e.type = 'preprimary')
) 
AND(
    e.title LIKE '%government%' 
)   
LIMIT 0, 10
```

I want to merge the first query with the second one, so that it should return all "preprimary" type schools with title like "government" located within 20KM radius and the result needs to be ordered by the distance.

How can I merge the two queries? I tried using JOINING the geodata table on the school table. But I dont know the remaining.  Sorry, if this is a silly question. I am pretty new to SQL world.

Comment: If the # of columns between the 2 queries is the same as well as the column format, you should use a union. Is that the case?

Comment: Do these tables have any foreign key?

Comment: @BrianDeMilia : Attached is the screenshot of the table http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=5s305&s=8#

Comment: @OscarPérez : I am very new to the SQL world, started learning it using google. So not sure about your question. Sorry

Comment: What I'm saying is that, to be able to JOIN data from two tables, you need something in common with them (what is called a foreign key). For example, you could have an school_id on your geodata table. Do you have something that allows you to relate both tables?

Comment: @OscarPérez: Yes, I have the "id" value in common between the two tables.

Comment: Ok, could you, please, post the table structure, so we can better help you?

Comment: @OscarPérez : I posted the screenshot at http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=5s305&s=8#

Comment: Then, I think the answer from @Mihai is correct....

Comment: @OscarPérez : But what I need is a reverse query, where Query 1 is merged to Query 2 like 

SELECT DISTINCT e.* FROM schools e  
JOIN geodata g ON e.id = g.id 
WHERE (
    (e.type = 'preprimary')
) 
AND(
    e.title LIKE '%government%' 
)   
AND (
 -- here goes thr location logic ---
)
LIMIT 0, 10

Comment: I think I've got it... See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 SELECT *
   From (
 SELECT DISTINCT e.* ,
       (6371 * acos( cos( radians(9.977364864079215) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(76.58620953448485) ) + sin( radians(9.977364864079215) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) )
        ) as distance
  FROM schools e  
LEFT JOIN geodata g ON e.id=g.id
 WHERE (e.type = 'preprimary')
   AND ( e.title LIKE '%government%' )
 ) as s
  Where s.distance  < 20
  Order by s.distance
```

Comment: Getting error #1054 - Unknown column 'distance' in 'where clause'

Comment: Try now, 'distance' wasn't calculated

Comment: Its working now. But what about the order_by? Isnt it a heavy query so that the distance has to be calculated twice?

Comment: You can add an order by ( I'm going to edit the answer in a minute). Althought distance is calculated twice, I guess the database engine could cache the results, so they don't have to be recalculated

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. Getting #1054 - Unknown column 's.distance' in 'where clause'

Comment: Great! Just as a curiosity, could you post the EXPLAIN from the resulting query?

Comment: I am sorry, I didnt understood your question. You mean what I want to do with the query?

Comment: No, I mean to use the `EXPLAIN` command on MySQL to get the execution plan. Just to know if it is using indexes and how it is joining the tables.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT school.* FROM
 ( SELECT geodata.id,
(6371 * acos( cos( radians(9.977364864079215) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(76.58620953448485) ) + sin( radians(9.977364864079215) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) 
        AS distance ,school.*
        FROM geodata LEFT JOIN school on geodata.id=school.id
        WHERE
         (school.type = 'preprimary')
        AND(
         school.title LIKE '%government%' 
         )   
        AND school.id IS NOT NULL
        HAVING distance < 20 )x
 ORDER BY x.distance 
        LIMIT 0 , 10;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But I think you have joined query 2 on query 1. Please correct me if I am wrong.

What I need is to join query 1 on query 2. Query 2 is the main query.

Comment: Which is the main criteria for keeping the data?Isnt distance?

Comment: The main query is finding "government preprimary" schools. the search is later refined to find those schools which are nearby.